# Scala: type check on yield that may return an empty list

Tags: scala

I have to following code in Scala, that's meant to return sentences.

```
val x: List[Word] = for (word <- words) yield {
  if (word.isLegit()) sentenceStartingWith(word)
}
```

I'm getting an error because the type of `x` is not `List[word]` but `Any` (because it may not yield anything). Casting didn't help.

The simple fix that came to mind was

```
val x: List[Word] = for (word <- words) yield {
  if (word.isLegit()) sentenceStartingWith(word)
  else List[Word]()
}
```

But this returns a list with a lot of empty lists as members. How can I get the behavior I want, which is to return a `List[word]` with all the items if finds (or empty if it finds none)

Comment: Just add `.flatten` at the very end of your second code sample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm getting an error because the type of x is not List[word] but Any

The compiler is inferring what you're trying to do. What it sees is that you only return a value when your `if` statement is matched, thus it implicitly returns `List[Any]` (via `List.canBuildFrom[Any]`) for anything that doesn't match the predicate. Thus, the common supertype of both `Seq[Any]`.

One possible way of doing this would be using a guard to filter out words first:

```
val x: List[Word] = for (word <- words if word.isLegit()) yield sentenceStartingWith(word)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
val x = words.withFilter(_.isLegit()).map(word => sentenceStartingWith(word))
```

Note methods in Scala are camelCase, and class names are PascalCase.

Comment: I think the for comprehension is equivalent to the `withFilter` snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
  val x: List[word] = for (word <- words  if (word.isLegit())) yield {word}
```